# USB camera on Raspberry PI showing black screen

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, webcam, v4l2

I'm working on one project in which I have to use industry camera (model ID: Imaginsource DFK 33UX178) that I have to access on Raspberry PI (OS: Debian Raspberry PI Desktop). **The camera was working fine before**. But once I connected with Windows Machine and adjust its setting using default windows camera app and then try to access using Raspberry PI OS, it is capturing black image only.

Below are commands I tried.

1. Command: sudo fswebcam test.jpg
   [Output of command 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyGrv.jpg)
2. Command: sudo fswebcam -S 1000 test.jpg
   [Output of command 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZkKg.jpg)

Moreover, I tried with OpenCV script (as below) but it is throwing error.

```
import cv2


with cv2.VideoCapture(0) as camera:
    ret = camera.set(3,640)
    ret = camera.set(4,480)
    
    try:
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        while(True):
            t1 = cv2.getTickCount()
            
            ret, frame = camera.read()
            frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)
            
            start_time = time.time()
            results = classify_image(interpreter, frame)
            elapsed_ms = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
            label_id, prob = results[0]
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
            
            # camera.annotate_text = '%s %.2f\n%.1fms' % (labels[label_id], prob,
            #                                         elapsed_ms)
            cv2.putText(frame, labels[label_id],(30,50),font,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
            
            cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)
            
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break
            
    finally:
        camera.release()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usb_api.py", line 4, in <module>
    with cv2.VideoCapture(0) as camera:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Although the command "lsusb" detecting the camera as below which is "The Imaging Source Europe GmbH"

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 199e:9082 The Imaging Source Europe GmbH 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I had doubt on camera's functionality so I tried with windows machine again and it is working fine with it.

Can someone please help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: sounds like it retains some settings such as exposure time or gain. check those. see how you can affect those via `v4l2-ctl`.

Comment: you can't use VideoCapture as a "context manager" (python thing). that's why the python exception. why did you try that? what makes you think it'd work?